# Scrapy - SQLalchemy Foreign Key not created in SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, scrapy

I tried to run Scrapy using itemLoader to collect all the data and put them into SQLite 3. I am success in gathering all the info I wanted but I cannot get the foreign keys to be generated in my ThreadInfo and PostInfo tables using `back_populates` with foreign key. I did try with `back_ref` but it also did not work.
All the other info was inserted to SQLite database after my Scrapy finished.

My goal is to have four tables, boardInfo, threadInfo, postInfo, and authorInfo linked to each others.

- boardInfo will have one-to-many relationship with threadInfo
- threadInfo will have one-to-many relationship with postInfo
- authorInfo will have one-to-many relationship with threadInfo and
  postInfo.

I used DB Browser for SQLite and found that the values of my foreign keys are `Null`.
I tried query for the value (threadInfo.boardInfos_id), and it displayed `None`. I try to fix this for many days and read through the document but cannot solve the issue.

How can I have the foriegn keys generated in my threadInfo and postInfo tables?

Thank you for all guidances and comments.

Here is my models.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Table, ForeignKey, MetaData
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String, Date, DateTime, Float, Boolean, Text
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

Base = declarative_base()

def db_connect():
    '''
    Performs database connection using database settings from settings.py.
    Returns sqlalchemy engine instance
    '''
    return create_engine(get_project_settings().get('CONNECTION_STRING'))

def create_table(engine):
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

class BoardInfo(Base): 
    __tablename__ = 'boardInfos'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    boardName = Column('boardName', String(100)) 
    threadInfosLink = relationship('ThreadInfo', back_populates='boardInfosLink') # One-to-Many with threadInfo

class ThreadInfo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'threadInfos'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    threadTitle = Column('threadTitle', String())
    threadLink = Column('threadLink', String())
    threadAuthor = Column('threadAuthor', String())
    threadPost = Column('threadPost', Text())
    replyCount = Column('replyCount', Integer)
    readCount = Column('readCount', Integer)

    boardInfos_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('boardInfos.id')) # Many-to-One with boardInfo
    boardInfosLink = relationship('BoardInfo', back_populates='threadInfosLink') # Many-to-One with boardInfo

    postInfosLink = relationship('PostInfo', back_populates='threadInfosLink') # One-to-Many with postInfo
    
    authorInfos_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('authorInfos.id')) # Many-to-One with authorInfo
    authorInfosLink = relationship('AuthorInfo', back_populates='threadInfosLink') # Many-to-One with authorInfo

class PostInfo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'postInfos'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    postOrder = Column('postOrder', Integer, nullable=True)
    postAuthor = Column('postAuthor', Text(), nullable=True)
    postContent = Column('postContent', Text(), nullable=True)
    postTimestamp = Column('postTimestamp', Text(), nullable=True)

    threadInfos_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('threadInfos.id')) # Many-to-One with threadInfo 
    threadInfosLink = relationship('ThreadInfo', back_populates='postInfosLink') # Many-to-One with threadInfo 
    
    authorInfos_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('authorInfos.id')) # Many-to-One with authorInfo
    authorInfosLink = relationship('AuthorInfo', back_populates='postInfosLink') # Many-to-One with authorInfo

class AuthorInfo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'authorInfos'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    threadAuthor = Column('threadAuthor', String())

    postInfosLink = relationship('PostInfo', back_populates='authorInfosLink') # One-to-Many with postInfo
    threadInfosLink = relationship('ThreadInfo', back_populates='authorInfosLink') # One-to-Many with threadInfo
```

Here is my pipelines.py

```
from sqlalchemy import exists, event
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from .models import db_connect, create_table, BoardInfo, ThreadInfo, PostInfo, AuthorInfo
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlite3 import Connection as SQLite3Connection
import logging

@event.listens_for(Engine, "connect")
def _set_sqlite_pragma(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    if isinstance(dbapi_connection, SQLite3Connection):
        cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;")
        # print("@@@@@@@ PRAGMA prog is running!! @@@@@@")
        cursor.close()

class DuplicatesPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Initializes database connection and sessionmaker.
        Creates tables.
        '''
        engine = db_connect()
        create_table(engine)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        logging.info('****DuplicatesPipeline: database connected****')

    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        session = self.Session()
        
        exist_threadLink = session.query(exists().where(ThreadInfo.threadLink == item['threadLink'])).scalar()
        exist_thread_replyCount = session.query(ThreadInfo.replyCount).filter_by(threadLink = item['threadLink']).scalar()
        if exist_threadLink is True: # threadLink is in DB
            if exist_thread_replyCount < item['replyCount']: # check if replyCount is more?
                return item
                session.close()
            else:
                raise DropItem('Duplicated item found and replyCount is not changed')
                session.close()
        else: # New threadLink to be added to BoardPipeline
            return item
            session.close()

class BoardPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Initializes database connection and sessionmaker
        Creates tables
        '''
        engine = db_connect()
        create_table(engine)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        '''
        Save scraped info in the database
        This method is called for every item pipeline component
        '''

        session = self.Session()

        # Input info to boardInfos
        boardInfo = BoardInfo()
        boardInfo.boardName = item['boardName']
        
        # Input info to threadInfos
        threadInfo = ThreadInfo()
        threadInfo.threadTitle = item['threadTitle']
        threadInfo.threadLink = item['threadLink']
        threadInfo.threadAuthor = item['threadAuthor']
        threadInfo.threadPost = item['threadPost']
        threadInfo.replyCount = item['replyCount']
        threadInfo.readCount = item['readCount']

        # Input info to postInfos
        # Due to info is in list, so we have to loop and add it.
        for num in range(len(item['postOrder'])):
            postInfoNum = 'postInfo' + str(num)
            postInfoNum = PostInfo()
            postInfoNum.postOrder = item['postOrder'][num]
            postInfoNum.postAuthor = item['postAuthor'][num]
            postInfoNum.postContent = item['postContent'][num]
            postInfoNum.postTimestamp = item['postTimestamp'][num]
            session.add(postInfoNum)
        
        # Input info to authorInfo
        authorInfo = AuthorInfo()
        authorInfo.threadAuthor = item['threadAuthor'] 

        # check whether the boardName exists
        exist_boardName = session.query(exists().where(BoardInfo.boardName == item['boardName'])).scalar()
        if exist_boardName is False:  # the current boardName does not exists
            session.add(boardInfo)

        # check whether the threadAuthor exists
        exist_threadAuthor = session.query(exists().where(AuthorInfo.threadAuthor == item['threadAuthor'])).scalar()
        if exist_threadAuthor is False:  # the current threadAuthor does not exists
            session.add(authorInfo)

        try:
            session.add(threadInfo)
            session.commit()

        except:
            session.rollback()
            raise

        finally:
            session.close()

        return item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code I can see, it doesn't look to me like you are setting `ThreadInfo.authorInfosLink` or `ThreadInfo.authorInfos_id` anywhere (the same goes for all of your FK/relationships).

For the related objects to be attached to a ThreadInfo instance, you need to create them and then attach them something like:

```py
        # Input info to authorInfo
        authorInfo = AuthorInfo()
        authorInfo.threadAuthor = item['threadAuthor'] 
        
        threadInfo.authorInfosLink = authorInfo
```

You probably don't want to session.add() each object if it's related via FK. You'll want to:

1. instantiate a `BoardInfo` object `bi`
2. then instantiate attach your related `ThreadInfo` object `ti`
3. attach your the related object eg `bi.threadInfosLink = ti`
4. At the end of all of your chained relationships, you can simply add `bi` to the session using `session.add(bi)` -- all of the related objects will be added through their relationships and the FKs will be correct.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.
When I added below code, I got error TypeError: Incompatible collection type: ThreadInfo is not list-like.
'boardInfo.threadInfosLink = threadInfo'

When I added 'threadInfo.authorInfosLink = authorInfo', it works, but this created duplicated 'authorInfo.threadAuthor' to my DB and I got FK as primary key from authorInfo table. So I have some duplicate authorName in my table and FK linked the the PK of newly created authorName.

How can I linked to the same BoardInfo.boardName or AuthorInfo.authorName?

Comment: So depending on the relationship and if it's a many-to-one and where you've decided to make it reside, you may need to .append() to the attribute rather than assign the related object to it. It's hard for me to read your models given the variable names and so forth, so I'm not following your intent but if a Board object will hold a collection of Threads, then give the relationship attribute a clear name like `threads = relationship('ThreadInfo', back_populates='boardInfosLink')` -- then if you want to append a thread to a BoardInfo `bi` it would be: `bi.threads.append(ti)` or similar

Comment: I have manage to get to work for your comment.
`threadInfo.authorInfosLink = authorInfo` is need for me to generate link of FK.

Answer (score 0):

Per the discussion in the comments of my other answer, below is how I would rationalize your models to make them make more sense to me.

Notice:

1. I have removed the unnecessary "Info" everywhere
2. I have removed explicit column names from your model definitions and will rely instead on SQLAlchemy's ability to infer those for me based on my attribute names
3. In a "Post" object I do not name the attribute PostContent, it's implied that the content relates to the Post because that's how we're accessing it -- instead simply call the attribute "Post"
4. I've removed all "Link" terminology -- in places where I think you want a reference to a collection of related objects I've provided a plural attribute of that object as the relationship.
5. I've left a line in the Post model for you to remove. As you can see, you don't need "author" twice -- once as a related object and once on the Post, that defeats the purpose of the FKs.

With these changes, when you attempt to use these models from your other code it becomes obvious where you need to use .append() and where you simply assign the related object. For a given Board object you know that 'threads' is a collection just based on the attribute name, so you're going to do something like `b.threads.append(thread)`

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Table, ForeignKey, MetaData
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String, Date, DateTime, Float, Boolean, Text
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

class Board(Base): 
    __tablename__ = 'board'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100)) 
    threads = relationship(back_populates='board')

class Thread(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'thread'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String())
    link = Column(String())
    author = Column(String())
    post = Column(Text())
    reply_count = Column(Integer)
    read_count = Column(Integer)

    board_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Board.id'))
    board = relationship('Board', back_populates='threads')

    posts = relationship('Post', back_populates='threads')
    
    author_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Author.id'))
    author = relationship('Author', back_populates='threads')

class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'post'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    order = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    author = Column(Text(), nullable=True)    # remove this line and instead use the relationship below
    content = Column(Text(), nullable=True)
    timestamp = Column(Text(), nullable=True)

    thread_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Thread.id'))
    thread = relationship('Thread', back_populates='posts')
    
    author_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Author.id')) 
    author = relationship('Author', back_populates='posts')

class AuthorInfo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'author'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String())

    posts = relationship('Post', back_populates='author') 
    threads = relationship('Thread', back_populates='author')
```